# find command does not seem to exclude specified directories

Tags: find

The `find` command should allow the exclusion of directories. I tried the following command.

```
find -name "clang" -not -path "./mnt/*
```

It is still searching the directory. I am missing something?

[image: output from find -not -path]

Comment: For reference, in future, please paste text output from commands rather than images.  They don't get indexed by search engines, and don't add any value for text based queries.

Answer (score 5):

Using `-not -path './mnt/*'` (or `! -path './mnt/*'`)  does not prevent `find` from descending into the `mnt` directory, it just means it won't do anything with the names it finds therein.

To get `find` to completely ignore a directory, use `-prune`:

```
find . -type d -name mnt -prune -o -type f -name clang -print
```

or

```
find . -path ./mnt -prune -o -type f -name clang -print
```

The first alternative will skip *any* `mnt` directory, while the second will skip the top-level one.

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes:

```
find -name "clang" -not -path './mnt/*'
```